# in WPF why the PasswordBox and TextBox are different controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, passwordbox

Already in `WinForm` we set a property to a `TextBox` and this easily changes the text style to password. I think this was a really good solution because all manner in `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` are same (sometime, we can set one style to these two kind of controls)

My question is: Why now in xaml, the `TextBox` and `PasswordBox` are different? What is the technical limitation of that WinForm's solution to dealing with passwords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the password box contains a sensible password it does not allow cut, copy, undo and redo commands.

[Source](http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html)

Without someone from the design team coming along to tell us for sure, I would suspect that to get this functionality having a separate control was the best way to achieve this.

In addition the PasswordBox is `sealed` meaning you can't derive your own custom control from it circumventing these restrictions.

[MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

So, ultimately the reason they're a separate controls is for security so that the user's password can't be intercepted.